# Validate a condition in default method in interface in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, default

I had a method in my interface that was implemented by many classes :

```
public interface MyInterface {
    Message createMessage(List<String> rawStrings);
}
```

There is a Validate condition I am adding to all the `createMessage` implementations :

```
public Message createMessage(List<String> rawStrings) {
    Validate.isTrue(!rawStrings.isEmpty(), "No rawstrings present");
    .....
}
```

I have been suggested to move the validate condition to the interface - but by doing so, I will be losing out on enforcing the class implementing my interface to implement this method.

Does this look like a good idea?

```
default Message createMessage(List<String> rawStrings) {
    Validate.isTrue(!rawStrings.isEmpty(), "No rawstrings present");
    return null;
}
```

Is this a good use of the default method in interfaces? How can I still ensure that the class implementing `MyInterface` also implements the method `createMessage`?

Comment: This is likely a better question for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You might want to look up Aspect-Oriented Programming and AspectJ.

Answer (score 3):

The original purpose of the `default` keyword was to add functionality to an existing interface without breaking existing implementations. This approach was taken by the Java Language team as a reluctant solution (i.e., instead of forcing *all* `List` implementations to implement a new method, a `default` method was added to `List`). In general, it is undesirable to move common code into a `default` method.

It is usually a better approach to introduce an abstract base class (ABC):

```
public interface MyInterface {
    Message createMessage(List<String> rawStrings);
}

public abstract class MyAbstractBaseClass implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public Message createMessage(List<String> rawStrings) {
        Validate.isTrue(!rawStrings.isEmpty(), "No rawstrings present");
        createValidMessage(rawStrings);
    }

    protected abstract Message createValidMessage(List<String> rawStrings);
}
```

Then, each implementing class extends the ABC instead:

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractBaseClass {

    @Override
    protected Message createValidMessage(List<String> rawStrings) {
        // ...do something...
    }
}
```

This is an implementation of the [Template Method Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method) that requires implementation classes to provide only post-validation logic.

Comment: Since the question is tagged with `design-patterns`, it's useful to note this answer is the [Template Method Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method).

Comment: @jaco0646 Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the answer.